# Keep session on page refresh codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on an application in Codeigniter. I want to keep the session even after page refresh but on page refresh it leads to login page again.

My configurations in config file are :

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;    // 30 * 60 //default 1800
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 3600;
```

Gone through many links but could not get any to make it work. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: increase your session time to $config['sess_expiration'] = '7200' for two days and try

Comment: $config['sess_expiration'] =0 is to make it expire never but still no luck.

Comment: replace your session library with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/b211adee89f5fd2192051e9c0826146bd150f469/system/libraries/Session.php

Comment: Which version of CI are you using? Check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468866/codeigniter-session-timeout-issue

Comment: @Rajesh : it is 2.1.4

Comment: Either you should update CI to 3 or you can extends the session library, ref - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468866/codeigniter-session-timeout-issue

Comment: Setting `$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 86400;` might also help.

Comment: @Saty : it worked. Thank u. May i know what is the exact parameter in the Session.php that u gave is responsible here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the value of "sess_expiration"

$config['sess_expiration']      = 1800;

Comment: it does not help and if you go through the whole question post, you will see the accepted answer given by Saty